# Unable to close Foundation's reveal modal when another button or enter key pressed

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to add functionality to close a modal for the user.

I would like to add a box that the user can click to close it as well as a method to close it when the user presses a key.

When I put simple alerts within my click event handlers, they do alert but do not close the modal.

Could someone help me on this please?

Thanks in advance.

Default function by Foundation:

```
<script>
      $(document).foundation();
      $('a.custom-close-reveal-modal').click(function(){
      $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'close');
    });
```

I've tried adding the following:

```
1) $("#done").on("click",function()
    {
      $('.close-reveal-modal').trigger('click');
    });

2) $("#done").on("click",function()
    {
      $('#myModal').foundation('reveal', 'close');
    });

3) $(document).keypress(function(e) {
     if(e.which == 13) {
       $('a.custom-close-reveal-modal').trigger('click');
       // alert("hi");
     }
```

HTML for the reveal modal box:

```
 <section id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
   ....content  goes here.....

 <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#10003;</a>// default option to close

 <input type="button" name="done" class="submit done" value="Done" id="done"/>//another option I made
</section>
```

Comment: By any chance, does the page happen to have more than one `#done` or trying to close the wrong modal ?

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this issue & was able to resolve this by just editing **foundation.css**

The class that trigger the link to close is

```
.close-reveal-modal
```

In foundation.css, look for the following class:

```
.reveal-modal .close-reveal-modal {    
   //some css blocks
 }
```

now remove all of the css blocks inside and create another class, for example:

```
.reveal-modal .close-x-btn{
   //paste the css blocks here from the .close-reveal-modal
 }
```

Overall your button should look like this

```
<a class="button close-reveal-modal">Cancel</a>
```

As for the "x" at the top right corner of the modal

```
<a class="close-reveal-modal close-x-btn" aria-label="Close">&times;</a>
```

> So now, you can close a modal using a button and the "x" on the top right corner while still
>   keeping the original style of the "x" link